# Doubts/Questions related to list partition on existing table with existing indexes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning, oracle19c

We want to partition two existing tables (`INVOICE_ITEMS` and `INVOICE_ITEMS_EVENTS`). These two existing tables already have indexes on it (as given in the image below).

INVOICE_ITEMS (existing indexes before table partition)

[image: INVOICE_ITEMS]

INVOICE_ITEMS_EVENTS (existing indexes before table partition)

[image: INVOICE_ITEMS_EVENTS]

- Do we need to drop these existing indexes and create partition
  indexes? Local or Global?
- What happens if we keep existing indexes instead of creating
  partition indexes?

We have many views which are using these tables (`INVOICE_ITEMS` and `INVOICE_ITEMS_EVENTS`). And these tables are joined using `item_obj_3` and `itemtype` columns in the both of the tables.

Below is an example view which is using the above two tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "XWDDSB128"."V_INVOICE_GETUSAGE" ("DOCUMENTID", "DEVICE_ID", "END_T", "IMPACT_CATEGORY", "RECORD_TYPE", "USAGE_CLASS", "DESTINATION", "CALLING_NUMBER", "CALLING_FROM", "CALLED_TO", "DURATION", "LOCATION", "VOLUME", "AMOUNT", "PROD_NAME", "EVENT_OBJ_2", "EVENT_OBJ", "CRBTINFO_EVENT_TYPE", "BUCKET_ID", "BALANCE_AMOUNT", "CHANNEL", "PRODUCT_NAME", "TYPE_STR", "BALANCE_TYPE", "BALANCE_OPTION", "PURCHASE_START_T", "RESOURCE_NAME", "AAC_ACCESS", "EVENT_TYPE") AS 
  SELECT            boi.DOCUMENTID,
                     boi.device_id ,
                     bie.end_t ,
                     impact_category ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_RECORD_TYPE record_type  ,
                     bie.telcoinfo_USAGE_CLASS usage_class  ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_LOCATION destination  ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_CALLING_NUMBER CALLING_NUMBER,
                     bie.vfqbalance_CALLING_FROM CALLING_FROM,
                     bie.vfqbalance_CALLED_TO CALLED_TO,
                     bie.vfqbalance_DURATION DURATION,
                     bie.vfqbalance_LOC_AREA_CODE location  ,
                     NVL(bie.gsminfoNUMBER, 0) volume  ,
                     NVL(bie.evttotal_amount, 0) amount  ,
                     bie.crbtinfo_prod_name prod_name ,
                     bie.EVENT_OBJ_2 ,
                     bie.event_obj,
                     bie.crbtinfo_EVENT_TYPE ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_VFQ_BUCKET_ID bucket_id  ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_AMOUNT balance_amount  ,
                     bie.crbtinfo_CHANNEL CHANNEL ,
                     bie.crbtinfo_PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_NAME ,
                     boi.TYPE_STR ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_TYPE balance_type  ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_OPTIONS balance_option  ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_purchase_start_t purchase_start_t ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_resource_name resource_name ,
                     boi.AAC_ACCESS,
                     bie.CRBTINFO_EVENT_TYPE event_type
        FROM (SELECT * FROM invoice_items WHERE ( ITEMTYPE = 'AR_ITEMS' OR ITEMTYPE = 'SUB_ITEMS')) boi
               JOIN invoice_items_events bie   ON  boi.item_obj_3 = bie.item_obj_3 AND boi.ITEMTYPE = bie.ITEMTYPE  
               and bie.vfqbalance_RECORD_TYPE is not null;
```

If we convert the tables into list partitioned tables , by adding a partition column named `schema_name` in both the tables, then,
how we can rewrite the above view so that it query only partitioned tables?

Answer (score 0):

On a partitioned table, *all* indexes will either by local or global. There is no third option of "neither". A global index is a non-partitioned index on a partitioned table. A local index is a partitioned index that shares the partitioning scheme of the table (so every table partition has its own set of index segments).

I presume that a partitioning column named `schema_name` suggests a very limited number of partitions. If this is true, local indexes would not harm performance noticeably even when the partitioning key is not used as an access predicate (which it appears from your question that this generally would not be the case).

Making the indexes local *would* cause a noticeable performance penalty *if* you do **(1) lots of high-frequency, (2) low-cardinality (e.g. single-row) seeks (3) without partition pruning (4) *and* there are many partitions** (as it has to seek in each one separately). All four of these factors need to be in place to make local indexes problematic: even if you have many partitions, if your predicates are not very selective the cost of fetching by ROWID from the table segment is far greater than the cost of walking the index segments, so again the penalty becomes inconsequential. And even if they *were* selective, if such seeks were relatively few and infrequent, again, not an overly large concern. Lastly, even if they were high-frequency, if the partitioning key is used as an access predicate and so prune partitions, there is no penalty. All four conditions have to be met for local indexes to be a problem.

But, if the indexes were local, you would have the benefit of being able to truncate, compress, move, drop, etc.. any of the list partitions separately without having to rebuild the entire index. You could do an online partition move with the `update indexes` option and have it complete in a reasonable amount of time (unlike with global indexes). There are numerous management benefits to local indexes. In fact, in our warehouses I generally prohibit the use of global indexes because of how they complicate management.

I cannot advise on changes to the view; views are queries that are themselves queried, which means additional predicates can be applied to them, totally changing the nature of the overall SQL and how it should work. If it is natural to your data to include the partitioning key (`schema_name`) in the join, that will likely help, either by pruning in a nested loops join (and so reducing index seeks) or by reducing the size of the inputs to a hash join if you were to apply a predicate to that column from outside the view. So by all means add that if you can.

Comment: So, can we say that the existing indexes on those tables are global by default?

Comment: @to-find Partitioning a table requires dropping and creating the table anew. In recent versions Oracle has permitted an `alter table` to do the partitioning, and there has long been options through `dbms_redefinition`, but all these under the covers drop and recreate the table internally, just with reduced syntax. I never use these mechanisms so don't know what they do with indexes. but if you do the partitioning manually (a single CTAS statement followed by index/constraint additions) you will have to create the indexes and simply by leaving out the "local" keyword you get a global index.

Comment: @to-find So if you want them local, which I generally always do, you must add the "`local`" keyword. Check the docs for whether/how other partitioning means allow for specifying index locality. If you make a mistake and it doesn't do what you want, simply drop the indexes and recreate them how you want them.